# Empty variable print '' when quoted

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script like this:

```
mkdir "$test"
```

If `$test` is empty, as with nothing then touch will complain with this:

```
touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory
```

If I remove the `"` then I get the behavior I'm expecting `mkdir: missing operand`.

The issue is If I ever have filenames with spaces in $test it will break my script. I need to do it in a way that `$test` can be empty or have spaces in it, and do not mess with my command either way.

In my real script the command line I'm using should just ignore `$test` if it's empty like it happens when not quoted, but need to work with spaces too. The issue is this `''` stuff that appears in my command line.

Comment: @muru Thanks! I did not found it by googling, but I help this question will help people get to that question with different search keywords